# Place google maps in another div (images provided)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps api always required height:100%. How can i prevent this and place in a unknown height & width div?

based on my image, i got div position:fixed at bottom.

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Cf9TU3raXU_zuppO8K1DHcPmLrRN_HgaLgFPIchH6Vw/edit

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
#map { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom:115px; 
z-index: 1; 
overflow: 
hidden;
margin-left: 502px;
```

}